# Xamarin.Android App Bundle with "Bundle into native Assemblies" increases size but Play Console shows smaller download

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin team is planning to remove "Bundle into native assemblies" option and they claim that Android App Bundles should do the similar job on reducing app size especially. It looks true but confusing.

I created my app using "bundle into native assemblies" option checked and without.
Surprisingly using without this option, aab size was almost half. Normally when creating apk, it is other way around this option seems to be reducing apk size.

I have just compared both aab using Android Studio Apk Analyzer to see the difference. as you can see below, left side is "without Bundle into native Assemblies", right side is with. 
And When you unzip the aab, you can see that generated files are the same. Aab without this option generates also SO files which are kind of obfuscated. 
So looks like Xamarin team is right. Not sure about the performance gain because this option increases performance gain some people claimed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now the final check on google play console. I have uploaded both file one by one, to my surprise, google play console shows something else.

See below, version 6 is with bundle into native assemblies, version 7 is without bundle into native assemblies. 
How can this be? When aab size is 58.8mb vs 33.8mb but download sizes are almost the same and even smaller for the 58.8mb one. Is it a bug in google play console? because as you see above 2nd screenshot shows that for each abi sizes are totally different as there this "bundle_app_so" generated for "bundle into native assemblies" option and all the rest of the files in both are same sizes.

Further more google play console shows similar download size but larger aab has install size smaller on devices.

[image]

With Bundle into native assemblies

[image]

Without Bundle into native Assemblies

[image]

Comment: nice (and confusing) finding. Just to clarify, in your testing, your `version 6` is **with** `BundleAssemblies` option enabled and your `version 7` is **without** this option enabled right?

Comment: @SimonSays yes, thats right. I had a typo there. thanks for mentioning. I fixed it now.

Comment: so ... with your finding, isn't it still right to conclude that `BundleAssemblies` does help with decreasing the size with App Bundle? Since with/without `BundleAssemblies`, the download size is about the same, and with it, the `App Size on device` is indeed smaller

Comment: @SimonSays i am not 100% sure about it. after I have seen those on google play. I pushed aab with bundle into native assemblies but when i checked the install size on my Samsung s10 it was around 50mb, not 34 mb. So google might be wrong. I am not sure if maybe google estimated this for different type of phone. It makes also no sense why would smaller aab should install bigger than bigger one. Give it a try your app and let me know what you find. Bundle into native assemblies surely makes sense for apk but i think not for aab.